# Question concerning Integral operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

What are the conditions on the kernel $k(x,s)$ that guarantees that the integral operator $T : L_{1}(a,b) \longrightarrow L_{1}(a,b)$ where $Tf(x) = \int_{a}^{b} k(x,s) f(s) ds$ be Lipschitz continuous?

*My attempt* 
$k(x,s) : [a,b] \times [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ should be continuous on $a ≤ x,s ≤ b$, and $M = Sup_{x,s} |k(x,s)|$

Comment: In case $a,b$ are bounded, it is enough for $k$ to be in $L^\infty((a,b)\times (a,b))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\|Tf-Tg\|_1&\le\int_a^b\int_a^b|k(x,s)|\,|f(s)-g(s)|\,ds\,dx\\
&=\int_a^b|f(s)-g(s)|\Bigl(\int_a^b|k(x,s)|\,dx\Bigr)\,ds\\
&\le\Bigl(\sup_{a\le s\le b}\int_a^b|k(x,s)|\,dx\Bigr)\,\|f-g\|_1.
\end{align}
A suficient condition is
$$
\sup_{a\le s\le b}\int_a^b|k(x,s)|\,dx<\infty.
$$